# twig internal block won't work

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I am have one problem, my internal blocks on twig won't work.

This is my layout.html.twig file:

```
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
//some code here
</body>
```

This is my index.html.twig

```
{% extends ':layout:dashboard.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
//some code here
{% endblock body %}
```

and this is header.html.twig.

```
{% extends '@Dashboard/Dashboard/index.html.twig' %}

{% block header %}
//some code here
{% endblock header %}
```

Comment: What does won't work means ? Any error ? What are you expect ? Won't you want instead create header.html.twig extending index.html.twig, to [include](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) the header.html.twig inside the index.html.twig ?

Comment: Yes, I want to include header.html.twig inside the index.html.twig.
Template of header.html.twig don't render.

Comment: So in index.html.twig just code {% include 'xx:xx:header.html.twig' %} instead inside {% block header %} and remove {% block header %} from your header.html.twig